# Java sqlite group by regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, sqlite

I have a database table that contains file names and full path of the files.

For example `/home/user/parent_folders/file.txt` I want to make a list with each of the distinct folders that contains at least one of the files in the database.

Now, I have achieved this by selecting all rows from the database table, getting the path of each file and using a Set, to ensure distinct values.

Is there is a more efficient method to do this? For example, can I use the Group By in the SQL statement with a regular expression? In the database I didn't have the parent path of the file, but the complete path with the file name at the end of the path.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

"Group By" in your SQL statement will provide you with a shorter set of results, which means putting them into a datastructure will take less time. You will, as you say, need to regex out the filename.